# Image subtraction using opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm want to subtract one image from other.

This is what I have done so far.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('template.jpg',0)
img2 = cv2.imread('shot_one.jpg',0)

img3 = img1-img2

cv2.imshow('result',img3)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm getting error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python Programme/ATSS/subtra.py", line 7, in <module>
    img3 = img1-img2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I have followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425992/how-to-subtract-two-images-using-python-opencv2-to-get-the-foreground-object). Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that img1 and img2 loaded successfully?

Comment: Per http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html , OpenCV will return `None` when an imread fails.

Comment: @sturkmen Yes, img1 and img2 are loading successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error line `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'` clearly states that, One of your image path is invalid, Opencv doesn't throws error, when the path is invalid, instead it returns a `None` Object.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('template.jpg',0)
img2 = cv2.imread('shot_one.jpg',0)

if img1 and img2:
    img3 = img1-img2

    cv2.imshow('result',img3)
    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
else:
    print "Sorry the images weren't loaded properly."
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `img1` and `img2` are the same sizes? If not, matrix subtraction isn't defined and would throw an error.

Comment: The error defined in the question is not related to image size at all.  Read the error more carefully.